# Can I save changes to an XML file loaded directly in XAML through bindings?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I can load the XML file all with XAML binding and no code behind.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="xmlfile" Source="Books.xml"/>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource  xmlfile}, XPath=/catalog/book, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Id" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=@id}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Author" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=author}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Title">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding XPath=title, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

In the above I made the `title` editable but changing the title doesn't save it, just as a wild shot.

I was wondering since the code is loading the XML file great, could it save the changes to the file as well? What would I need to do save the changes?

**Update**

Thanks, this saves but not exactly to the same file. My books.xml file is project root folder, with save button, it saves a copy in the `bin\debug` folder. If I set the working directory to project root folder, it doesn't update the file but no errors either.

I also set the source in XAML to a absolute path so I know I am working with that file but saving throws exception in this case.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="xmlfile" Source="c:\\xml\\Books.xml"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

The exception is `The given path's format is not supported.`.

I also I tried the path with `c:/xml/books.xml`, the project reads the file in either way but saving throws the same exception.

So can I really save it to the same file? How do I direct it to do that?

Answer (score 1):

When you finish the work you have to save changes manually. It depends on your needs but usually when you close the application or when the user clicks on a button to save the work.

Access the resource and the `XmlDocument` uses as the binding source and save the XML document.

```
var xmlDataProvider = Resources["xmlfile"] as XmlDataProvider;
var xmlDocument = xmlDataProvider.Document;
var fileName = xmlDataProvider.Source.ToString();
xmlDocument.Save(fileName);
```

Comment: Thanks it did save the file but not really to the same file and there are issues when I tried to resolve the path.  I updated the question with what I tried, can you please see the update?